# Another Stack implementation in Java

Tags: java, beginner, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to write my own stack implementation using `LinkedList`. It looks like it is doing what it should doing. But how does it look from a design perspective?

If I will go for job interview and show such things to a interviewer, will they say: "that's looks nice" or they rather will look at me with weird look asking "who let you in"?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Stack <T> {
private T t;
private LinkedList<T> stack;


public Stack() {
    this.stack = new LinkedList<>();
}

public void push(T t) {
    stack.add(t);
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    if(stack.size()!=0){
        return false;
    } return true;
}

public T pop(){
    if(!isEmpty()) {
        return stack.removeLast();
    }
    return t;
}

public T peek(){
    if(!isEmpty()){
        return stack.getLast();
    }
    return t;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> It looks like it is doing what it should be doing.

I don't understand that remark. In particular, you posted no unit tests or other evidence of the target code being exercised in usual cases and in edge cases.

```
    private T t;
```

What is that? The ctor doesn't affect it. It doesn't appear to contribute to any Stack invariants. Why can't pop() and peek() simply return `null`?

```
    if (stack.size() != 0) {
        return false;
    } return true;
```

Don't show that at an interview. Use the more natural `return stack.size() == 0` instead.

For some workloads involving a large stack, this implementation will show worse performance than one that uses a doubly linked list.

Answer (score 1):

my addition to the very good answer of @J_H:

1. Java `LinkedList` has a `isEmpty()` method.  why is it better to use that than quering the size? because you might choose to replace `LinkedList` with another Collection implementation, one that implements `isEmpty()` differently.
2. in the `push()` method I would prefer to call `LinkedList`'s `addLast()` method since it saves the doubt where `add()` adds the new item.